# Calculating value for unique column entries using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have not been able to find a similar question across SO. I am quite new to dplyr in general.

Consider a toy data frame of some sales statistics

```
df <- data.frame(
  added = c("2020-10-05", "2020-10-30", "2020-11-04", "2020-12-10", "2020-12-14"),
  closed = c("", "2020-11-05", "2020-12-10", "", ""),
  value = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
  stage = c("Quote", "Won", "Lost", "Quote", "Quote")
)
```

It contains the date a deal was `added`, when it was `closed`, the deal `value` and the current `stage` of the deal. If a deal is not won or lost, it does not have a `closed` date. I want to calculate the *pipeline value*, i.e. the value of deals which are not yet won or lost, for each unique entry in the `added` and `closed` column (since these are the only times where the pipeline value can change).

I have gotten it to work through a mix of base R and dplyr. First I create a data frame of dates:

```
date_df <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2020-10-01"),as.Date(Sys.Date()),1))
colnames(date_df) <- c("date")
```

My choice of starting date is arbitrary as long as it is before the first date in the `added` column. Then I evaluate this expression for each entry in `date_df` through a loop:

```
library(tidyverse)
pipeline <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(date_df)) {
    pipeline <-
        df %>%
        filter(
            (added <= date_df$date[i] & closed > date_df$date[i] & closed < Sys.Date()) |
            (added <= date_df$date[i] & stage != "Won" & stage != "Lost")
        ) %>%
        summarise(pipeline = sum(value))
    date_df$pipeline[i] <- pipeline
}
```

Which correctly gives me:

```
> date_df
         date pipeline
1  2020-10-01        0
2  2020-10-02        0
3  2020-10-03        0
4  2020-10-04        0
5  2020-10-05      100
6  2020-10-06      100
7  2020-10-07      100
8  2020-10-08      100
9  2020-10-09      100
10 2020-10-10      100
11 2020-10-11      100
12 2020-10-12      100
13 2020-10-13      100
14 2020-10-14      100
15 2020-10-15      100
16 2020-10-16      100
17 2020-10-17      100
18 2020-10-18      100
19 2020-10-19      100
20 2020-10-20      100
21 2020-10-21      100
22 2020-10-22      100
23 2020-10-23      100
24 2020-10-24      100
25 2020-10-25      100
26 2020-10-26      100
27 2020-10-27      100
28 2020-10-28      100
29 2020-10-29      100
30 2020-10-30      300
31 2020-10-31      300
32 2020-11-01      300
33 2020-11-02      300
34 2020-11-03      300
35 2020-11-04      600
36 2020-11-05      400
37 2020-11-06      400
38 2020-11-07      400
39 2020-11-08      400
40 2020-11-09      400
41 2020-11-10      400
42 2020-11-11      400
43 2020-11-12      400
44 2020-11-13      400
45 2020-11-14      400
46 2020-11-15      400
47 2020-11-16      400
48 2020-11-17      400
49 2020-11-18      400
50 2020-11-19      400
51 2020-11-20      400
52 2020-11-21      400
53 2020-11-22      400
54 2020-11-23      400
55 2020-11-24      400
56 2020-11-25      400
57 2020-11-26      400
58 2020-11-27      400
59 2020-11-28      400
60 2020-11-29      400
61 2020-11-30      400
62 2020-12-01      400
63 2020-12-02      400
64 2020-12-03      400
65 2020-12-04      400
66 2020-12-05      400
67 2020-12-06      400
68 2020-12-07      400
69 2020-12-08      400
70 2020-12-09      400
71 2020-12-10      500
72 2020-12-11      500
73 2020-12-12      500
74 2020-12-13      500
75 2020-12-14     1000
76 2020-12-15     1000
77 2020-12-16     1000
78 2020-12-17     1000
79 2020-12-18     1000
80 2020-12-19     1000
81 2020-12-20     1000
82 2020-12-21     1000
```

Basically, I sum the value of open deals for each date. However, this appears to me as a very inefficient approach. The real data set is quite extensive, and to evaluate at each date takes quite some time.

I am only really interested in the expression to be evaluated for each unique entry in `added` and `closed` as described above. Are there any elegant solutions with the use of dplyr which accomplishes this, (preferably) without creating a new object? The idea is to later plot it and send it to a shiny app, so a reduction in computing time could be crucial.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

To show an example for two dates `2020-11-04` and `2020-11-05`:

On `2020-11-04`, three deals (entry 1-3 in the data) are not either `Lost` or `Won`, hence the pipeline value for that date is `600`.

On `2020-11-05`, one deal is now `Lost` (second entry in the data), and the pipeline value drops to `400`.

So, when a deal is closed, the pipeline value decreases, and when a deal is added, the pipeline value increases.

Values for all dates are added to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach will also be useful

```
result <- dff %>% mutate(id = row_number(),
                         added = as.Date(added),
                         closed = as.Date(closed)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c("added", "closed"), names_to = "activity", values_to = "dates") %>%
  mutate(activity = factor(activity, levels = c("added", "closed"), ordered = T)) %>%
  arrange(dates, activity) %>%
  mutate(val = cumsum(value*case_when(activity == "added" ~ 1,
                                      activity == "closed" ~ -1,
                                      TRUE ~ 0))) %>%
  group_by(dates) %>% summarise(val = min(val))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
  dates        val
  <date>     <dbl>
1 2020-10-05   100
2 2020-10-30   300
3 2020-11-04   600
4 2020-11-05   400
5 2020-12-10   500
6 2020-12-14  1000
7 NA             0
```

`dput(dff)` used

```
> dput(dff)
structure(list(added = structure(c(18540, 18565, 18570, 18606, 
18610), class = "Date"), closed = structure(c(NA, 18571, 18606, 
NA, NA), class = "Date"), value = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500), 
    stage = c("Quote", "Won", "Lost", "Quote", "Quote")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

If you want to plot the results use `complete` and `fill` as

```
plot <- result %>% filter(!is.na(dates))  %>%
  complete(dates = seq.Date(min(dates), max(dates), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(val) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = dates, y = val))

plot
```

[image]

Comment: Very neat! How would I get about the double value for `2020-12-10` ? The end result is `500`, but your solution contains two entries for that date. Also, I would appreciate if you could add `mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>%` after `pivot_longer`, that way the original `df` can be used.

Comment: This looks good! For completeness I would remove `select(dates, val) %>%` since it is redundant and change `summarise(val = last(val))` to `summarise(val = min(val))` for easier interpretation. Marked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why u're using the `closed < Sys.Date()` do you have future closed deals, if so this code will account for it:

```r
df %>%
 mutate(across(closed:added, lubridate::ymd), cl = closed < Sys.Date()) %>%
  pivot_longer(c(closed, added), values_to="date") %>%
   filter(!is.na(date)) %>%
    group_by(date) %>%
     summarise(pipeline=sum((stage=="Quote" | cl) *value)) %>%
      mutate(pipeline=cumsum(pipeline)) 
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  date       summed
  <date>      <dbl>
1 2020-10-05    100
2 2020-11-05    300
3 2020-10-30    500
4 2020-12-10   1200
5 2020-11-04   1500
6 2020-12-10   2200
7 2020-12-14   2700
```

Comment: It was not made clear, but future closed deals are indeed possible, hence `closed < Sys.Date()`. The result presented here is not correct. For example, the value for `2020-11-04` should be `600` and for `2020-11-05` should be `400`.

Comment: Please also see my edit with clarifications in the original post.